# How to add 2 columns and a table inside a WordPress Tab Elementor without using HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, elementor, wordpress-gutenberg

I am using WordPress, in this WordPress I have an event page. In the Event page there is a banner, a tabs section, and a register section.

I want to be able to add a table and 2 columns in side a tab item without using html and css so that the others can easily edit it.

I know I can achieve this with HTML and CSS, but I want to know if there is a solution more friendly to those who do not know html and css so they can easily edit if they wish.

Comment: Are you wanting them to be able to login to Wordpress and add things through its editor?